# Node.js callbacks and recursion

Tags: node.js, recursion, callback

I don't understand how to call a function recursively in node.js for example:

```
var releaseStock = function (callback) {

  getItems(function (err, items) {
    if (err) {
      return callback(err);
    } else {
      if (items) {
        return callback(items);
      } else {
        setTimeout(function() {
          releaseStock(callback);
        }, 5000); 
      }
    }
  });
};
```

How can i make it work?

Comment: You'l need to specify what exactly you're trying to do. As it stands, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: Sorry, i'll explain better, in this releaseStock method, you will have a method to bring items, so, if you get items, you'll make something with them, make it wait the process for x seconds, and then call releaseStock again.

Comment: My question is about how to call the method again, with callback or not

Comment: Please update your question with relevant information rather than commenting here. It may also be helpful to provide some sample input, output, and pseudocode possibly.

Comment: Add ALL further explanation about your question to the question itself using the "Edit" link.  In other words, fix your question so it contains all the necessary information for us to answer.  We do not want infomation that is  essential to understanding the question to only be present in comments.  The question needs to be clear on it's own.

Comment: As your question stands now, it successfully make a recursive call to `releaseStock()` when there is still something in items.  But, it probably needs to pass the same callback to `releaseStock(callback)` that was originally passed.  And, it is completely unclear to us whether this accomplishes anything useful because you have not told us anything about what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: I've already edited the example code, it was totally wrong...yes I was not sure about passing callback by param, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but I suspect it is something along the lines of:

```
var releaseStock = function(callback) {

  // get items from somewhere:
  var items = getItems();

  if (!items) {
    // if there are no items, try again (recurse!):
    return releaseStock(callback);
  }

  // if there are items, give them to the callback function:
  return callback(items);
};
```